# PL/SQL variable declaration: Is it INOUT if i don't explicitly specify?

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_DISCOUNT
(
  v_have_list SALES_PRODUCT_TY_LIST,
  ...
)
```

Is `v_have_list` an `INOUT` variable?

Comment: No, the default is `IN` as described in the [manual](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/subprograms.htm#CIHGFAFI)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default is `IN`.

See the following [table](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/subprograms.htm#BCFHBGBI).